# Fix header to top of page with horizontal scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css, header, horizontal-scrolling

I have a navigation header at the top of every page. I'd like the user to be able to scroll the horizontal overflow with a scrollbar. I understand this isn't possible with just CSS, but can any help me with the JavaScript portion?

If this is too general, I'll post my project's code, but it's pretty extensive.

Ex:

| Example Header | About | Contact | Bl | (Cut off)

<------------------> (Scroll bar)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a version of my code:

```
function reposition(){
    var el = document.getElementById('header');
    var ScrollLeft = document.body.scrollLeft;
    if (ScrollLeft == 0)
    {
        if (window.pageXOffset)
            ScrollLeft = window.pageXOffset;
        else
            ScrollLeft = (document.body.parentElement) ? document.body.parentElement.scrollLeft : 0;
    }
    el.style.left = "-" + ScrollLeft + "px";
}
```

Replace `'header'` with your header's id.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot! Does the window.pageXOffset have any compatibility issues in browsers?

Comment: `window.pageXOffset` is only for Firefox/ NS6+/ Chrome. and `document.body.scrollLeft` is for IE

Answer (score 1):

It's possible with CSS. Set your header to use `overflow: auto;`.

Example: http://jsbin.com/edopor/4/edit

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Sorry I didn't make myself clear. I want the header to interact with the main scroll-bars.