# fix div to window top while allowing for horizontal scroll for overflow on window resize

Tags: html, css

I would like to fix my navigation bar to the top of the browser window, but allow horizontal scroll for nav items for nav items that may have overflowed when the browser width is decreased. An example is the gmail nav bar being fix to top but still horizontally scrollable when the window width is decreased.

Currently I use the following css for the div which fixes the div to top but does not allow horizontal scrolling because it is fixed(tried overflow:scroll but doesn't do anything):

```
position: fixed;
top:0
overflow:scroll;//does nothing
```

Answer (score 0):

If you give it a `right` and `left` value, it should scroll: http://jsbin.com/edopor/4/edit

Comment: thanks, but I was looking for a single scroll bar at the bottom of the browser, not one for the top and another for the bottom.  An Example is the nav bar in gmail when you srhink the browser width

Comment: In that case, I believe there's an answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12291226/fix-header-to-top-of-page-with-horizontal-scroll/12291301#12291301 And I read that one the same way too :(

Answer (score 0):

If `overflow:auto;` doesn't work it may be the possible lack of a doctype.

Comment: Also, it may help to set the width and height.  That may be why it isn't working.